# C#, trying to create human readable type name

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I am trying to generate a human readable string for e.g. `ICollection<string>` or any other generic ICollection<> / IList<> / IEnumerable<>

In order to do this I use amongst others the following routine:

```
public static string HumanReadableTypeName(this Type aType)
    {
        if (aType == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(ReflectionExtensions)}.{nameof(HumanReadableTypeName)}");
        var lBaseType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(aType);
        if (lBaseType != null)
            return cNullableHdr + HumanReadableTypeName(lBaseType);
        if (aType == typeof(string))
            return aType.Name;
        if (aType.IsArray)
        {
            var elementTypeName = HumanReadableTypeName(aType.GetElementType());
            var lBuilder = new StringBuilder(elementTypeName);
            for (var i = 0; i < aType.GetArrayRank(); i++) // add brackets for each dimension
                lBuilder.Append("[]");
            return lBuilder.ToString();
        }
        var listtype = aType.GetInterfaces().Where(x => x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IList<>)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (listtype != null)
        {
            var itemType = listtype.GetGenericArguments().Single();
            var itemTypeName = HumanReadableTypeName(itemType);
            return $"IList<{itemTypeName}>";

        }
        var collectiontype = aType.GetInterfaces().Where(x => x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (collectiontype != null)
        {
            var itemType = collectiontype.GetGenericArguments().Single();
            var itemTypeName = HumanReadableTypeName(itemType);
            return $"ICollection<{itemTypeName}>";

        }
        var enumerabletype = aType.GetInterfaces().Where(x => x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (enumerabletype != null)
        {
            var itemType = enumerabletype.GetGenericArguments().Single();
            var itemTypeName = HumanReadableTypeName(itemType);
            return $"IEnumerable<{itemTypeName}>";
        }
        return aType.Name;
    }
```

Trouble is that when I pass `typeof(ICollection<string>)` as an argument I get `IEnumerable<string>` as an answer.

In the debugger I entered:

```
typeof(ICollection<string>).GetInterfaces()
```

with as result a collection of just 2 elements:

```
+       [0] {Name = "IEnumerable`1" FullName = "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]"}  System.Type {System.RuntimeType}
+       [1] {Name = "IEnumerable" FullName = "System.Collections.IEnumerable"}  System.Type {System.RuntimeType}
```

So it seems the `ICollection<>` interface isn't listed!

What confuses me also is that the following statement:

```
typeof(ICollection<string>).Name
```

returns:

```
"ICollection`1"
```

So the debugger appears to be able to show it is an ICollection of some kind.

Am I overlooking something, is this featured behavior, or is it a bug in VS22 / .NET7

TIA

Comment: `GetInterfaces()` return the interfaces that the type _implements_ or _inherits_. Obviously, `ICollection<T>` does not inherit `ICollection<T>`. If you do `typeof(IList<string>).GetInterfaces()`, for example, you do get `ICollection\`1`. Consider checking if the type itself is an `ICollection<T>`.

Comment: Why do you expect `ICollection<string>` to inherit from itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Etienne and 4168... reported, I overlooked the fact that an interface definition does not support *itself*.

So I fixed the method, and now it looks like this, in addition having optional support to look for the supported interfaces, and support for `IDictionary<,>`

```
    public const string cNullableHdr = "Nullable";

    public static string HumanReadableTypeName(this Type aType, bool checkSupportedInterfaces=true)
    {
        if (aType == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(ReflectionExtensions)}.{nameof(HumanReadableTypeName)}");
        var lBaseType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(aType);
        if (lBaseType != null)
            return cNullableHdr + HumanReadableTypeName(lBaseType);
        if (aType == typeof(string))
            return aType.Name;
        if (aType.IsArray)
        {
            var elementTypeName = HumanReadableTypeName(aType.GetElementType());
            var lBuilder = new StringBuilder(elementTypeName);
            for (var i = 0; i < aType.GetArrayRank(); i++) // add brackets for each dimension
                lBuilder.Append("[]");
            return lBuilder.ToString();
        }
        // check if the type IS one of the most supported collection types
        if (aType.IsGenericType && aType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IDictionary<,>))
        {
            var genericargs = aType.GetGenericArguments();
            var keyTypeName = HumanReadableTypeName(genericargs[0]);
            var valueTypeName = HumanReadableTypeName(genericargs[1]);
            return $"IDictionary<{keyTypeName},{valueTypeName}>";
        }
        if (aType.IsGenericType && aType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IList<>))
        {
            var itemType = aType.GetGenericArguments().Single();
            var itemTypeName = HumanReadableTypeName(itemType);
            return $"IList<{itemTypeName}>";
        }
        if (aType.IsGenericType && aType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>))
        {
            var itemType = aType.GetGenericArguments().Single();
            var itemTypeName = HumanReadableTypeName(itemType);
            return $"ICollection<{itemTypeName}>";

        }
        if (aType.IsGenericType && aType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
        {
            var itemType = aType.GetGenericArguments().Single();
            var itemTypeName = HumanReadableTypeName(itemType);
            return $"IEnumerable<{itemTypeName}>";
        }
        if (checkSupportedInterfaces)
        {
            var dictionaryType = aType.GetInterfaces().Where(x => x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IDictionary<,>)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (dictionaryType != null)
            {
                var genericargs = dictionaryType.GetGenericArguments();
                var keyTypeName = HumanReadableTypeName(genericargs[0]);
                var valueTypeName = HumanReadableTypeName(genericargs[1]);
                return $"IDictionary<{keyTypeName},{valueTypeName}>";
            }

            // check if the type SUPPORTS one of the most supported collection types
            var listtype = aType.GetInterfaces().Where(x => x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IList<>)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (listtype != null)
            {
                var itemType = listtype.GetGenericArguments().Single();
                var itemTypeName = HumanReadableTypeName(itemType);
                return $"IList<{itemTypeName}>";

            }
            var collectiontype = aType.GetInterfaces().Where(x => x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (collectiontype != null)
            {
                var itemType = collectiontype.GetGenericArguments().Single();
                var itemTypeName = HumanReadableTypeName(itemType);
                return $"ICollection<{itemTypeName}>";

            }
            var enumerabletype = aType.GetInterfaces().Where(x => x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (enumerabletype != null)
            {
                var itemType = enumerabletype.GetGenericArguments().Single();
                var itemTypeName = HumanReadableTypeName(itemType);
                return $"IEnumerable<{itemTypeName}>";
            }
        }
        // otherwise, just return the system type name
        return aType.Name;
    }
```